# Parsing file in bash with asterisk

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Working on a script to partially convert cobol into pl/sql and I'm struggling to convert cobol comments to Oracle comments.

The lines look like

```
******************
```

So the plan was to parse each line in the file, and if the first character was an asterisk, add a double dash -- to the beginning of the line. However the asterisk is a special character and I can't seem to get bash to handle it.

Ideas?

Edit.
Example section of cobol.

```
************************
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
************************

PROGRAM-ID.
```

Those lines with the asterisk need to become

```
--**********************
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
--**********************
```

I've replaced the $firstChar with all sorts of iterations but end up with "command not found" because bash is still reading the asterisk as a command and not as a string character.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    firstChar=$(cut -c-1 <<< "$line")

    if [["$firstChar" == \**]]; then
       echo "Asterisk found, replacing with two dashes"
    fi

done < "$1"
```

Comment: An example usage would be helpful, are you using sed or grep or something? But usually you can use a slash ( \ ) to escape special characters.

Comment: I had tried \* but it still wasn't working.

Comment: So show us what you have tried.

Comment: Added to original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the character with a `\`

```
if [[ $line == \** ]]
 then
   echo "-- whatever"
 fi
```

The second * is the wildcard, so it checks whether the line starts with the asterisk.

**EDIT:** If you are comparing only the first character, you can remove the second `*`, which is suposed to represent the rest of the string.

```
if [[ $firstChar == \* ]]; then
  echo "Asterisk found..."
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Returns "[[**************: command not found"

Comment: Don't forget the space after the `[[` and the one before the `]]`

Comment: That works! Now onto appending the double dash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `sed`

```
sed 's/^*/--*/g'
```

replace `*` from the beginning of line with `--*`.  Interestingly this works even though the first searched `*` is not escaped.  Also, `g` is unnecessary since there is only one possible match per line due to `^`. As commented below, the correct syntax should be

```
sed 's/^\*/--*/'
```

Comment: You need to backslash-escape the asterisk. An unquoted `*` is a repetition operator. Also the `/g` is clearly gratuitous if there is only one substitution to be made. I think you mean `s/^\*\*/--/`